# Javascript load php file with spesific function for different div

Tags: javascript, php

a good day. I just learned about javascript, here I'm making a code to display the latest data on mysql each time an automatic reload with javascript. From the code I made, displaying humidity & temp data for each div. But I want to display separate data for each div (container). For example, div: humidity will display only humdity data and so on. Can you help me. I am very grateful for your help.

this is the code from index.php :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
$('#humidity').load('tampil.php');
    $('#temperature').load('tampil.php');
}, 200);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Humidity: </h4> 
<div id="humidity"></div>
<h4>Temperature: </h4>      
<div id="temperature"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

this the code of tampil.php :

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$result2=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY `waktu` DESC LIMIT 1");
if($result2!==FALSE){
    while($lastrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $last_temp=$lastrow["temperature"];
        $last_rh=$lastrow["humidity"];

        echo "$last_rh";
        echo "$last_temp";
    }
    }
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make one single Ajax call, return both values as JSON and simply update the contents in the divs.

I've added comments through out the code, explaining what things do and why I do them.

*Note:* The code is untested so there might be some errors, but this is the gist of how to do it.

Another thing, this will update the divs 5 times per second. That's a lot!

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    // Make the variable global so we can access it from 
    // outisde jQuery's on load function
    var refresId;

    // wrap it in $(function(){}) to make it wait until the page
    // has been fully loaded before executing the code
    $(function () {
        refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            // Make one call to return both values
            $.get('tampil.php').done(function (result) {
                // Just update the contents of the divs
                $('#humidity').html(result.humidity);
                $('#temperature').html(result.temperature);
            });
        }, 200);
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$result2 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY `waktu` DESC LIMIT 1");

// Since we only want one row, no need to loop it
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

// Create an array that we can convert as json.
// The ?? is short hand for "isset($x) ? $x : null" which is good to 
// have so the code won't break if the query won't return what we expect.
$response = [
    'temperature' => $row['temperature'] ?? null,
    'humidity'    => $row['humidity'] ?? null,
];

// Let the response know we're returning json
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Encode the array as json and echo the result
echo json_encode($response);

// We're done so let's stop the script from keep executing.
exit;
```

Comment: thank you, this works very well. Yes, I tried the editor with an error regarding "unexpected ?" but for the result there is no problem.Can you helpme how to add "°C" after temperature data or "%" after humidity ? thanks

Comment: @user99 - I don't know what you mean by _"I tried the editor with an error regarding "unexpected ?""_ What editor? Are you talking about your IDE? Make sure it validates your code using PHP 7 (the null coalesce operator `??` wasn't introduced until PHP 7). To append a string to the values, you can do that in JS. Just concatenate the string you want to append when you output it: `$('#humidity').html(result.humidity + '%')`.

Comment: I use Dreamweaver CC. where at the line "'temperature' => $ row ['temperature'] ?? null," notifications appear "unexpected '?'"

Comment: If you can't change what PHP version it should check against, I would recommend using some other IDE where you can do that. There are more differences in PHP 7 than that operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would package your php data as a json object and make one call and then parse the data and your front end, but here's a way to get it working the way you've started it.

You can wrap your data in divs with ids in the php file and then tell the jQuery load function to just grab the data from a certain div on the page. Here's how you would modify your files.

PHP

```
echo "<div id='humidity'>$last_rh</div>";
echo "<div id='temperature'>$last_temp</div>";
```

JS

```
$('#humidity').load('tampil.php #humidity');
$('#temperature').load('tampil.php #temperature');
```

Comment: thank you, yes you're right, it's better to try using json objects